# mongoose: vaildate portion of schema searching for field already in db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to write a custom vaildator for a mongoose object. The idea is that the `name` field must be a name value of a pre-existing object in a different collection. I'm doing this like so:

```js
var seshSchema = new Schema(
    {
        student:
            {
                type: String,
                validate: [
                function(input)
                {

                    studentColl.find({name: input},function(err, result){
                        if(err)
                        {
                            throw err;
                        }

                        return result.length > 0; //how do I make this get returned by the function in vaildate's array?

                    });


                }, "nope"]
            },
        tutor: {type: String},
        blockTimes: [blockTime],
        record : [pastSession]
    }
);
```

What I'm trying to do is validate this piece based on whether or not there exists certain criteria in a different collection (studentColl). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: [Mongoose Validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

There they describe the usage of async validators [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators).

According to this documentation your code should be looking like this:

```js
var seshSchema = new Schema({
    student: {
        type: String,
        validate: {
            validator: function(v, cb) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    studentColl.find({ name: v }, function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            cb(false);
                        } else {
                            cb(result.length > 0);
                        }
                    });
                }, 1);
            }
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: @Schulace: Has this answer helped you?

Comment: I've tried doing this, but the return there only returns to the function passed into find, not the first function. basically I need to run this asynchronous method synchronously.

Comment: I updated my anwer which now uses an async validator. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I found a different solution using the deasync module, but I'll be sure to look into the one you've posted. thanks so much for your help

Comment: update: Your solution is a lot less clunky, although the timeout is unnecessary and was likely just used in the documentation as an example of something asynchronous.